# Find an element and move it below another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to move an element `.nav.item` which contains `a href` with text "My Wish List" to below div `#move-below-this`, roughly like this:

```js
$(".nav.item").insertAfter("#move-below-this");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div id="move-below-this"></div>
</div>
<ul class="nav items">
  <li class="nav item current"><strong>Account Dashboard</strong></li>
  <li class="nav item"><a href="http://testa.dev/sales/order/history/">My Orders</a></li>
  <li class="nav item"><a href="http://testa.dev/downloadable/customer/products/">My Downloadable Products</a></li>
  <li class="nav item"><a href="http://testa.dev/wishlist/">My Wish List</a></li> <!--I want to move this element -->
  <li class="nav item">
    <span class="delimiter"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="nav item"><a href="http://testa.dev/customer/address/">Address Book</a></li>
  <li class="nav item"><a href="http://testa.dev/customer/account/edit/">Account Information</a></li>
  <li class="nav item"><a href="http://testa.dev/vault/cards/listaction/">Stored Payment Methods</a></li>
  <li class="nav item"><a href="http://testa.dev/paypal/billing_agreement/">Billing Agreements</a></li>
  <li class="nav item">
    <span class="delimiter"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="nav item"><a href="http://testa.dev/review/customer/">My Product Reviews</a></li>
  <li class="nav item"><a href="http://testa.dev/newsletter/manage/">Newsletter Subscriptions</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i want to move the .nav.item element which contains a href with text "My Wish List"  to below the div element with id #move-below-this

Comment: Got it. I added an answer for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:contains()` selector to find an element by it's text content.

However, in this case you need to ensure that the `li` you move is still contained in a `ul` after it's moved to keep your HTML valid. To do that you can use `wrap().parent()`, like this:

```js
$('.nav.item:contains("My Wish List")').wrap('<ul />').parent().insertAfter('#move-below-this');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div id="move-below-this"></div>
</div>
<ul class="nav items">
  <li class="nav item current"><strong>Account Dashboard</strong></li>
  <li class="nav item"><a href="http://testa.dev/sales/order/history/">My Orders</a></li>
  <li class="nav item"><a href="http://testa.dev/downloadable/customer/products/">My Downloadable Products</a></li>
  <li class="nav item"><a href="http://testa.dev/wishlist/">My Wish List</a></li> <!--I want to move this element -->
  <li class="nav item">
    <span class="delimiter"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="nav item"><a href="http://testa.dev/customer/address/">Address Book</a></li>
  <li class="nav item"><a href="http://testa.dev/customer/account/edit/">Account Information</a></li>
  <li class="nav item"><a href="http://testa.dev/vault/cards/listaction/">Stored Payment Methods</a></li>
  <li class="nav item"><a href="http://testa.dev/paypal/billing_agreement/">Billing Agreements</a></li>
  <li class="nav item">
    <span class="delimiter"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="nav item"><a href="http://testa.dev/review/customer/">My Product Reviews</a></li>
  <li class="nav item"><a href="http://testa.dev/newsletter/manage/">Newsletter Subscriptions</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i don't need ul element i just need the li element

Comment: That's invalid HTML. *Every* `li` element must be contained within a `ul`.

Comment: ok thanks it works now, by the way do you know how to change the ''My Wish List" text?